# How can I block the javascript function use CSP?

Tags: javascript, security, content-security-policy

I have two functions and want to allow function c. How can I do?
Never change script. Only block function b()...

```
<script nonce="12345">
    function b() { return 'b'; }
</script>

<!-- allow me -->
<script nonce="12345">
    function c() { return 'c'; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case just use different `nonce` values and then in your CSP allow only one of them.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-[allowed nonce value]'
```